# How would I animate my sprite, but with human-like movements?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a game in html5 and javascript where this sprite moves. I can easily make it move, that's any easy fear I want it to move with human characteristics. Like if i press right, it's legs start to move back and forth and walk, not just the whole image moving. The link to the sprite is: http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t384/Kenny00K/16_zps739f55b8.jpg

and my source code is here:
              
                
             
            
            var canvas;
            var ctx;
           var gameLoop;
            var img=new Image();
          var  whatLoop;

```
       //The Map Of the game
   var mapx=0;
      var mapy=0;
    var mapw=600;
        var maph=400;

  //Platform 1
     var x1=0;
      var x2=85;
     var x3=350;
     var x4=5;

   //Platform 2
   var y1=330;
   var y2=150;
      var y3=265;
   var y4=5

      //Platform 3
   var z1=100;
    var z2=200;
    var z3=265;
    var z4=5;

   //Platform 4
  var w1=335;
    var w2=275;
    var w3=265;
```

var w4=5;

```
  //Platform 5
  var a1=100;
   var a2=335;
  var a3=265;
   var a4=5;



    //Good Guy
      x=0;
   y=35;
     xy=5;
    var frames=4;
       var currentFrame=0;


     function game()
    {
      canvas=document.getElementById("myc");
  if(canvas.getContext)
       {
  ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
       img.src="http://i1057.photobucket.com/…
      gameLoop=setInterval(gamec,25);
       whatLoop=setInterval(whatkey,1);
       window.addEventListener("keydown", whatkey);
      }
    }

       function gamec()
   {

         ctx.fillStyle="black";
          ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.rect(mapx,mapy,mapw,maph);
       ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
         ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x1,x2,x3,x4);
   ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();



     ctx.fillStyle="green";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(y1,y2,y3,y4);
    ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();

      ctx.fillStyle="#680000 ";
  ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(z1,z2,z3,z4);
    ctx.closePath();
               ctx.fill();

           ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
                  ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.rect(w1,w2,w3,w4);
                  ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();

          ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,100,100);
         ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

     ctx.fillStyle="red";
            ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.rect(a1,a2,a3,a4);
         ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

    }


    function whatkey(evt)
     {
    if(evt.ketCode==39)
 {
         x+=xy;
       }

         }



  </script>
              </head>

    <body onLoad="game()">

   <canvas id="myc" width="800" height="900"></canvas

      </body>
           </html>
```

once you execute the code if you press right arrow the image moves right. However, how would you make the legs move back and forth as well, so it looks more human-like and realistic.

Comment: You would just have to separately animate the legs.  Perhaps by swapping out the image to a animated GIF (if you don't to actually animate pixels in canvas).

Comment: You can make a tiled CSS sprite and loop through the different animations as long as the image is in a "moving" state.

Comment: Create a proper sprite-sheet. It should have each frame for each animation you require. Define the regions/positions of animations in your script, and use the current status/action to determine what animation should be playing.

Comment: You might want to look into [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/), it simplifies a good many things.